# Missing environment variables

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am using the library https://cir.is/docs/overview to load my environment variables as follows:

```
object EnvironmentLoader {

  val db: ConfigValue[Postgres] =
    (
      env("POSTGRES_URL").as[NonEmptyString],
      env("POSTGRES_USER").as[NonEmptyString],
      env("POSTGRES_PW").as[DatabasePassword].secret
    ).parMapN(Postgres)

}
```

I have set the variables in the shell:

```
POSTGRES_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users
POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
POSTGRES_PW=password
```

When I run `sbt test` it shows:

```
[error] - GET /user test with invalid UUID
[error]   ConfigException$$anon$1: configuration loading failed with the following errors.
[error] 
[error]     - Missing environment variable POSTGRES_URL.
[error]     - Missing environment variable POSTGRES_USER.
[error]     - Missing environment variable POSTGRES_PW.
[error] 
[error]   ConfigException.scala:57      ciris.ConfigException$#apply
[error]   ConfigError.scala:114         ciris.ConfigError#throwable
[error]   ConfigValue.scala:176         ciris.ConfigValue#$anonfun$load$1
[error]   Resource.scala:118            cats.effect.Resource#$anonfun$fold$1
[error]   <snipped>                     cats.effect.internals.<...>
[error]   JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp#apply
[error]   BlockContext.scala:94         scala.concurrent.BlockContext$#withBlockContext
[error]   <snipped>                     cats.effect.internals.<...>
[error]   <snipped>                     java.util.concurrent.<...>
```

How to set environment variables for `sbt`?

Comment: You meant `export POSTGRES_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez You are awesome man.